# Entity Framework 6.0 NVarchar vs Varchar

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a site running in Azure that is causing me headaches. I see a select query as being an expensive query in Azure that is coming from EF.

The query is a select against a `varchar` column in the database, but from EF, it is turning it into `nvarchar(4000)`, causing the query to time out.

Here is how I'm calling the query in the code:

```
var myObject = db.MyTable.FirstOrDefault(cm => cm.MyField == entryModel.MyField.Trim());
```

I have searched through many resources explaining how EF uses `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`, so I've tried adding this annotation to the field in my model class:

```
[Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
```

When that didn't work, I tried adding this to the `OnModelCreating` method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().Property(x => x.MyField).IsUnicode(false);
```

I've also tried this to force all strings to `varchar`:

```
modelBuilder.Properies<string>().Configure(x => x.HasColumnType("varchar(1000)"));
```

The query is still causing performance issues that, according to the activity monitor in the database, the query is still showing as this:

```
(@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000))SELECT TOP (1) 

blah blah fields

FROM [dbo].[MyTable] AS [Extent1]

WHERE ([Extent1].[MyField] = (LTRIM(RTRIM(@p__linq__0)))) OR (([Extent1].[MyField] IS NULL) AND (LTRIM(RTRIM(@p__linq__0)) IS NULL))
```

Any ideas as to what is causing this?  I'm at a point right now that I'm about to just write a stored procedure to call instead of using this EF query.

*****EDIT*****
Thanks to [@Robert Harvey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey) and [@StriplingWarrior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120955/striplingwarrior) for their help.  Removing the inline trim allowed EF to recognize the varchar change as well as removing the TRIM from the actual SQL calls.

```
var myField = entryModel.MyField.Trim();
var myObject = db.MyTable.FirstOrDefault(cm => cm.MyField == myField);
```

Thanks!

Aaron

Comment: Those `LTRIM(RTRIM` calls are almost certainly the cause of the performance problems, not your varchar conversion.

Comment: [It appears](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2969820/120955) Entity Framework should pick a non-unicode parameter type if it knows your column type, but I wonder if the trimming interferes with that logic. If you extract `entryModel.MyField.Trim()` into a variable and use that variable in your Where expression, does that change the parameter type?

Comment: welp, you were both correct.  the trim seemed to have messed with the parameter type in sql somehow.  it is now showing up as varchar, and also helped performance considerably.  Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 2):

If using annotations, consider specifying the Column and the MaxLength separately.

```
[Required]
[Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
[MasLength(20)]
string MyString { get; set; }
```